# Salesforce database structure for sales cloud and service cloud

Tags: database

Do any one here have any doc related to database model of salesforce. Model of sales cloud and service cloud. I go through doc which salesforce have https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/data_model.htm but its to confusing. If there any youtube video or doc form where I can understand it much better how salesforce is using there objects of marketing, sales and service cloud apps.

Comment: How and what specifically is this confusing to you ? I'm not aware of many video's or recorded talks about the datamodel that are in any way better understandable than the documentation you refer to. To really answer you and help you, it's important to understand why you are unable to understand the data model in the way it's described in the documentation.

  Consider updating your question with more detail, so that we can answer also with more detail.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to get this information is to sign up for a free Developer Edition of Salesforce [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/en/signup), and then go to **Setup** > **Build** > **Schema Builder**.

You can then pick and choose which objects you want to look at and see all of the relationships between them.

There are also some more traditional schema diagrams available in the documentation:

- [Salesforce Data Model](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/data_model.htm)
- [Sales Objects](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_erd_majors.htm)
- [Support Objects](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_erd_support.htm)

There are also these two presentations from Dreamforce last year which concentrate on the administration of Sales Cloud and Service Cloud but should hopefully help your understanding of how the features and objects actually work and interact:

- [Hands-on Training: Get Started with Sales Cloud Administration](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MSp61khlP9s)
- [Hands-on Training: Get Started with Service Cloud Administration](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fJFlIqtlscI)

Comment: Hi @Alex i went through this traditional schema diagrams but not able to understand. Its confusing a lot.

Comment: @Anu Have you tried setting up a Developer account and using the objects rather than just reading about them? It might help you to understand how it fits together.

Comment: perhaps a valid question could be that do you guys have a combined diagram between Sales and Service cloud objects. I am looking for one if anyone have one to share. Else I will put together one myself.

Answer (score 0):

There are some third party solutions to getting a data model from Salesforce.   The Schema Builder is good for relatively small models, but if you want to use a more 'industrial strength' modelling environment, then you probably want to be able to get the metadata out of SFDC and do some scoping and analysis.    I suggest you google Safyr, which is a tool for just this.   Its from Silwood Technology.